# Formatting double

Tags: c#, formatting, double

I have this big number (a `double`): `123456789012345.012345`

That should be represented as: `123.456.789.012.345,01` using the `pt-BR` format.

This is the format `{0:###,###,###,###,##0.00}` that I'm using, yet this is the result:

[image]

As you can see, after 13 characters, the format starts to round the decimal places. How can we display correctly the number without rounding?

Comment: You're simply exceeding what can be represented by a double (the double representation of your literal value). The format is not the problem. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`double`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9.aspx) only has 15-16 digits of precision, so any significant digits after that are truncated.

[`decimal`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx) has 28-29 digits of precision, and should be used if you need to represent the number as a decimal number without any loss of precision.

Answer (score 2):

```
decimal numb = 123456789012345.012345m;
string strNumb = string.Format(new CultureInfo("pt-BR"), "{0:###,###,###,###,##0.00}", numb);
string strNumb2 = string.Format(new CultureInfo("pt-BR"), "{0:###,###,###,###,##0.00}", 123456789012345.012345m);
```

You can use decimal instead of double.